# Call function in OpenModelica

Tags: openmodelica

Is it possible to execute Modelica functions in OpenModelica without performing a simulation?

In Dymola I can call them from:

- the package browser, using *Call Function...*
- the command line, using the full class path
- the script editor, again with the full class path

Is there anything comparable in OpenModelica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In OMEdit,

1. the Libraries Browser, using Call function
2. the OpenModelica Compiler CLI under the Tools menu, using the full class path

Note that option 1 is only available in the latest version.

Comment: Thanks! I am using the latest stable version (v1.12.0). Is it in the 1.13.0 beta1 or in the nightly release?

Comment: -d=gen flag needs to be activated for this.

Comment: Its in both 1.13.0 beta1 and nightly but not in 1.12.